# How to find the Set - Subset of two files from the command line?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, set, zsh

I have two files with sorted lines. One file (B) is a subset of the other file (A). I would like to find all lines in A that ARE NOT in B. Ideally, I would like to create a file (C) that contains these lines. Is this possible in Unix? I'm looking for a one line command to do this instead of writing a script. I looked at the `join` and `diff` commands, but I could not find a command option to do this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will suppress common lines:

```
comm -3 a b
```

Comment: And in case you'd ever like to find the common lines in both files, you can use `comm -12 a b`

Comment: To create a third file c one would use of course `comm -3 a b > c`

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
grep -v -f B A > C
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with diff as well. Diff (unlike @johlo's grep answer) cares about order, works on non-sorted files (unlike @johnshen64's comm answer) :

```
$ cat a
a
b
c
d
e
$ cat b
a
b
f
d
e
$ diff -dbU0 a b
--- a   2012-05-18 16:02:30.603386016 -0400
+++ b   2012-05-18 16:02:45.547817122 -0400
@@ -3 +3 @@
-c
+f
```

So you can use a pipeline to get just the omitted lines—considering order:

```
$ diff -dbU0 a b | tail -n +4 | grep ^- | cut -c2-
c
```

Answer (score 1):

This `join` command will do what you're asking:

```
join -v 1 fileA fileB > fileC
```

Demonstration:

```
$ cat fileA
a
c
d
g
h
t
u
v
z
$ cat fileB
a
d
g
t
u
z
$ join -v 1 fileA fileB
c
h
v
```

This assumes sorted files as you stated in your question. For unsorted files:

```
join -v 1 <(sort fileA) <(sort fileB)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Awk Solution**

Input files

**a**

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

**b**

```
ccc
ddd
eel
```

**Code**

```
awk ' NR==FNR { A[$0]=1; next; }
{ if ($0 in A) { A[$0]=0; } }
END { for (k in A) { if (A[k]==1) { print k; } } } ' a b > c
```

**c** (Output file)

```
bbb
aaa
```

Comment: OP specifically asked for a non-script solution. Given, you've put the script on the command line, but...